# Is the function $xy-(\sin{y})(\sin{x} +2y)$ non-positive near $(0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, graphing-functions

As in the title is the function $f(x,y)=xy-(\sin{y})(\sin{x} +2y)$ non-positive near $(0,0)$?

The wolfram claims so - [see the plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy-(sin(y))(sin(x)%20%2B2y)%3C%3D0). On the other hand one can argue as follows. Choose arbitrary small $x>0$ since $x> \sin x$ one can find $y>0$ small enough to have $x> \sin x +2y$ since also $y> \sin y$ one easel gets $xy \ge(\sin{y})(\sin{x} +2y)$ and wolfram confirms that also for some concrete numbers - [see this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2F1000)*(1%2F100000000000000)-(sin(1%2F100000000000000))*%20(sin(1%2F1000)%20%2B2%2F100000000000000)). What am I missing? Thanks in advance for Your help.

Comment: So all that proves is that you should not put too much trust in plots. Trust the algebra.

Comment: With higher resolution, the apparent neighborhood of $(0,0)$ where $f$ is non-positive would appear less and less certain.

Comment: Thank you very much I just wanted to know that I am not missing something.

Comment: You logic seems right (+1), and the numerical evaluation confirms it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand as Taylor series around $x=0$
$$A=x y-\sin (y) (\sin (x)+2 y)=-2 (y \sin (y))+x (y-\sin (y))+\frac{1}{6} x^3 \sin (y)+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Peform another expansion of the previous around $y=0$ to get for $y << x$ $$A\approx \frac 16 x^3 y$$ which matches the number in the second run.

Using, as in the second run, $x=10^{-3}$ and computing with illimited precision, what we can notice is that $A >0$ as soon as $y < 10^{-11}$.

Answer (score 2):

*Claim.* The function $f$ takes both signs in the neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

*Proof.* Consider the pullback of $f$ along the curve $y=x^4$, i.e., the function
$$\eqalign{g(x)&:=f(x,x^4)=x^5-\sin(x^4)(\sin x + 2 x^4)\cr
&=x^5-\left(x^4-{x^{12}\over 6}+?x^{20}\right)\left(x-{x^3\over6}+2x^4+?x^5\right)\cr
&={x^7\over6}+?x^8\qquad(x\to0)\ ,\cr}$$
where the $?$ acts as standin for various functions that are analytic near $x=0$. It follows that
$${\rm sgn}\bigl(g(x)\bigr)={\rm sgn}(x)\qquad (x\to0)\ .$$

Comment: Could the $?x^n$ be replaced with the more standard $O(x^n)$?

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, but the $O$-statement is weaker. My $?$ replaces an analytic function, or convergent power series. Apart from this: Doing calculations (e.g., dividing two power series) with pencil and paper is much more convenient this way than with the $O$-notation.

Comment: That' the problem here: The dependence of $x$ and $y$ determine the result. You have choosed one type of dependence but exist unlimited many. This must be taken into account, because the OP has made no restrictions.

Comment: @user90369: An approach of this kind can not be used to prove that the claim $f(x,y)\leq0$ is true. But a single counterexample (provided in this answer) suffices to prove that the claim is false.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Thanks for your comment, I will check. :-)

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: It's right ... (+1) :-)

Answer (score -3):

Considering limit from all sides
You get,
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \lfloor xy-\sin y (\sin x +2y)\rfloor = 0$$

Which indicates the fact that,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0) } f(x,y) \to 0^{+}$$

Thus,
The function is positive near the given the point.

Comment: If the limit is zero, the values of the function can still be both positive or negative, and even equal to zero, at different nearby points -- which is actually the case with this function.

Comment: Ya you are right..